# Building AOSP, vendor_module_check.mk fail

Tags: android, syntax, makefile, build-process, android-source

I'm trying to include the Google Mobile Services apps in my AOSP build for Nexus 10 (manta).  I created a `vendor` folder in my root directory and modified the full_manta.mk file by adding these lines:

```
# Include GMS apps
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/generic.mk)
$(call inherit-product, vendor/google/products/gms.mk)
```

Next, I do `. build/envsetup.sh` and then `lunch` (I select 13 for full_manta-user-debug build).  Then I type `make -j32` to build and get the following error:

```
build/core/tasks/vendor_module_check.mk:60: *** Error: vendor module "Books" in  vendor/google/apps with unknown owner "" in product "full_manta".  Stop.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.  I'm also a make file noob so I can't really understand what's in the `vendor_module_check.mk` file other than the fact that the error is being generated around here:

```
$(foreach m, $(_vendor_check_modules), \
  $(if $(filter vendor/%, $(ALL_MODULES.$(m).PATH)),\
    $(if $(filter $(_vendor_owner_whitelist), $(ALL_MODULES.$(m).OWNER)),,\
      $(error Error: vendor module "$(m)" in $(ALL_MODULES.$(m).PATH) with unknown owner \
        "$(ALL_MODULES.$(m).OWNER)" in product "$(TARGET_PRODUCT)"))\
    $(if $(ALL_MODULES.$(m).INSTALLED),\
      $(eval _vendor_module_owner_info += $(patsubst $(PRODUCT_OUT)/%,%,$(ALL_MODULES.$(m).INSTALLED)):$(ALL_MODULES.$(m).OWNER)))))

endif
```

Anyone have any similar experiences or know what the error is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer found here:

http://www.aosp.me/2012/09/productrestrictvendorfiles.html

For my case, I was building for manta.  In the file /device/samsung/manta/full_manta.mk,change:

```
PRODUCT_RESTRICT_VENDOR_FILES := owner path
```

to

```
PRODUCT_RESTRICT_VENDOR_FILES := false
```

and then run `make -j32`

;)